# Is it possible to add additional parameters to an OnClick event in addition to the default "Sender: TObject" in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, onclick, parameter-passing

I am doing my A2 computing project in Delphi and have encountered a problem when it comes to adding additional parameters to an event procedure.

I am creating a number of Labels (TLabel object) and storing them in an array under my main form, "form1".

This is what I have currently:

**The declaration of the array of labels and the corresponding ClickEvent procedure with the standard (Sender: TObject) parameter passed.

```
 public
     InventoryLabel : array [0..23] of TLabel;
     procedure InventoryLabelClick(Sender: TObject);
```

**This is the procedure of the ClickEvent matching the one declared above. (The contents of the procedure is very messy but is relevant to the question and is what I am using to get by currently.)

```
Procedure TForm1.InventoryLabelClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
if sender = InventoryLabel[0] then imgInvItem.Picture.LoadFromFile(redcarddeck[redcardpositionsofinventory[0]].cardpic);
if sender = InventoryLabel[1] then imgInvItem.Picture.LoadFromFile(redcarddeck[redcardpositionsofinventory[1]].cardpic);
if sender = InventoryLabel[2] then imgInvItem.Picture.LoadFromFile(redcarddeck[redcardpositionsofinventory[2]].cardpic);
if sender = InventoryLabel[3] then imgInvItem.Picture.LoadFromFile(redcarddeck[redcardpositionsofinventory[3]].cardpic);
if sender = InventoryLabel[4] then imgInvItem.Picture.LoadFromFile(redcarddeck[redcardpositionsofinventory[4]].cardpic);
if sender = InventoryLabel[5] then imgInvItem.Picture.LoadFromFile(redcarddeck[redcardpositionsofinventory[5]].cardpic);
if sender = InventoryLabel[6] then imgInvItem.Picture.LoadFromFile(redcarddeck[redcardpositionsofinventory[6]].cardpic);
if sender = InventoryLabel[7] then imgInvItem.Picture.LoadFromFile(redcarddeck[redcardpositionsofinventory[7]].cardpic);
if sender = InventoryLabel[8] then imgInvItem.Picture.LoadFromFile(redcarddeck[redcardpositionsofinventory[8]].cardpic);
if sender = InventoryLabel[9] then imgInvItem.Picture.LoadFromFile(redcarddeck[redcardpositionsofinventory[9]].cardpic);
if sender = InventoryLabel[10] then imgInvItem.Picture.LoadFromFile(redcarddeck[redcardpositionsofinventory[10]].cardpic);
if sender = InventoryLabel[11] then imgInvItem.Picture.LoadFromFile(redcarddeck[redcardpositionsofinventory[11]].cardpic);
if sender = InventoryLabel[12] then imgInvItem.Picture.LoadFromFile(redcarddeck[redcardpositionsofinventory[12]].cardpic);
if sender = InventoryLabel[13] then imgInvItem.Picture.LoadFromFile(redcarddeck[redcardpositionsofinventory[13]].cardpic);
if sender = InventoryLabel[14] then imgInvItem.Picture.LoadFromFile(redcarddeck[redcardpositionsofinventory[14]].cardpic);
if sender = InventoryLabel[15] then imgInvItem.Picture.LoadFromFile(redcarddeck[redcardpositionsofinventory[15]].cardpic);
if sender = InventoryLabel[16] then imgInvItem.Picture.LoadFromFile(redcarddeck[redcardpositionsofinventory[16]].cardpic);
if sender = InventoryLabel[17] then imgInvItem.Picture.LoadFromFile(redcarddeck[redcardpositionsofinventory[17]].cardpic);
if sender = InventoryLabel[18] then imgInvItem.Picture.LoadFromFile(redcarddeck[redcardpositionsofinventory[18]].cardpic);
if sender = InventoryLabel[19] then imgInvItem.Picture.LoadFromFile(redcarddeck[redcardpositionsofinventory[19]].cardpic);
if sender = InventoryLabel[20] then imgInvItem.Picture.LoadFromFile(redcarddeck[redcardpositionsofinventory[20]].cardpic);
if sender = InventoryLabel[21] then imgInvItem.Picture.LoadFromFile(redcarddeck[redcardpositionsofinventory[21]].cardpic);
if sender = InventoryLabel[22] then imgInvItem.Picture.LoadFromFile(redcarddeck[redcardpositionsofinventory[22]].cardpic);
if sender = InventoryLabel[23] then imgInvItem.Picture.LoadFromFile(redcarddeck[redcardpositionsofinventory[23]].cardpic); 
end;
```

**This is the bit of code that creates the labels and gives them their attributes.

```
for I := 0 to 23 do
  begin
    InventoryLabel[i] := TLabel.Create(nil);
      with InventoryLabel[i] do
        begin
          Parent := Inventory;
          left := 8;
          OnClick := InventoryLabelClick;
          visible := false;
        end;
end;
```

This is all very well and works(ish) however I want to pass a parameter when I call the "InventoryLabelClick" procedure in this case the variable "I" which will be the reference of which label is pressed. This will allow me to remove all of the "if sender = inventorylabel[x]" (x being any of the numbers above) and instead replace with just the second bit "imgInvItem.Picture.LoadFromFile(redcarddeck[redcardpositionsofinventory[I]].cardpic);" but with the parameter "I" instead of the number "x" (same as above).

I tried the following edits to see if it would work.

**Change it in the declaration

```
Public
   procedure InventoryLabelClick(Sender: TObject; I: Integer);
```

**Change it for the procedure in the implementation

```
Procedure TForm1. InventoryLabelClick(Sender: TObject; I: Integer);
```

**Then when the event it assigned to the object

```
for I := 0 to 23 do
  begin
    InventoryLabel[i] := TLabel.Create(nil);
      with InventoryLabel[i] do
        begin
          Parent := Inventory;
          left := 8;
          OnClick := InventoryLabelClick;
          visible := false;
        end;
end;
```

**the sender parameter is default so there is no need to declare it in the first case. However when there are multiple parameters it asks for both.

When run, this returns the error message "

> E2010 Incompatible types:'TNotifyEvent' and 'procedure, untyped pointer or untyped parameter'

" I take this to mean that I have declared the parameters wrong.

Is anybody able to help me solve this problem? If it turns out that it is impossible to pass an additional parameter like I have attempted to do above, can anybody suggest a way of making the code a bit neater?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Save the "i" value in the TLabel's Tag property.

```
for I := 0 to 23 do begin
  InventoryLabel[i] := TLabel.Create(nil);
  with InventoryLabel[i] do begin
    Parent := Inventory;
    Tag := i;
    left := 8;
    OnClick := InventoryLabelClick;
    visible := false;
  end;
end;
```

Then, in your OnClick event, type cast Sender to TLabel and read off the Tag value to get the label clicked on:

```
Procedure TForm1.InventoryLabelClick(Sender: TObject);
  begin
    imgInvItem.Picture.LoadFromFile(redcarddeck[redcardpositionsofinventory[TLabel(Sender).Tag]].cardpic);
  end;
```

Comment: If you use nil as the Owner, don't forget to free the TLabel instances to avoid memory leaks

Comment: Just want to point out that this is potentially unsafe if you were to assign InventoryLabelClick as the event handler of a control that isn't a TLabel. I know its unlikely. Just something to keep in mind.

Comment: I think this may be the cleanest way to do it. @mjn: doesnt Parent := Inventory make that the owner? Inventory belongs to the main form.

Comment: No, @Josh, ownership and parentage are totally separate concepts. The labels should be owned by the form. You can put them wherever you want.

Comment: This does not answer if it is possible to add a parameter in an OnClick Event.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you do it like this?

```
Procedure TForm1.InventoryLabelClick(Sender: TObject);
var i : integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 23 do
    if sender = InventoryLabel[i] then imgInvItem.Picture.LoadFromFile(redcarddeck[redcardpositionsofinventory[i]].cardpic);
end;
```

Of course, the best way would be to make InventoryLabel not TLabel, but a custom class that capsulates a TLabel and a LoadPicture method, so you can do:

```
Procedure TForm1.InventoryLabelClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Sender.LoadPicture;
end;
```

But this will be a bit more work.

Answer (score 2):

You can't change TNotifyEvent's signature. You would have to create a custom label control with its own OnClick event that accepts additional parameters. This is probably more work than is warranted for a school project and in general I don't recommend writing a custom control unless you have no other alternative.

There is an easier way however.

```
Procedure TForm1.InventoryLabelClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := Low(InventoryLabel) to High(InventoryLabel)do
    if Sender = InventoryLabel[I] then
      imgInvItem.Picture.LoadFromFile(redcarddeck[redcardpositionsofinventory[I]].cardpic);
end;
```

Comment: If you use High, then why don't you use Low as well? It's good practice not to assume any lower bounds when you have a built-in function that can ensure you always get it right... Also, you should loop from Low to High - not from 0 to High-1.

Comment: Point taken. I work with a few different languages and had just come from C# so it took a while to switch gears.